# How to have an EditText stuck to the soft keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make something like the image below, where the keyboard automatically opens when the activity starts and the `EditText` and the send button stick to the keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code to pop up the soft keyboard automatically when an activity launches

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(youredittext, 0);
```

Make sure that you have not define  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your manifest.xml.

To make an Edittext attach with the footer,use the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="10.0dip"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_send_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ib_send"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ib_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_send_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/et_send_bar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1px"
            android:background="@drawable/chatsend_bg"
            android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_dark_normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tkanks for your answer ! but how to have a bar like that stuck to the soft keyboard ?

Comment: That is not a big issue.Just create a edittext and set its atribute as alignparentBotton=true(if your parent is a relative layout)...then it should work

Answer (score 0):

To show Keyboard at start of `Activity` you need to use like this:

```
 <activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"  />
```

From Android Docs:

> **stateVisible**
>
> *The soft keyboard is visible when that's normally appropriate (when
>   the user is navigating forward to the activity's main window).*

To hide Keyboard at start of `Activity` you need to use like this:

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

From Android Docs:

> **stateHidden**
>
> *The soft keyboard is hidden when the user chooses the activity — that
>   is, when the user affirmatively navigates forward to the activity,
>   rather than backs into it because of leaving another activity.*

This setting will hide soft keyboard when user enters new Activity (even if EditText control gains the focus). Soft keyboard will be shown only when user clicks the edit box control.

Comment: I guess he is asking to launch the keyboard when activity opens...not hiding it.

Comment: If you have not specify any thing in xml or java code then it will automatically show keyboard at start of activity

Comment: yes focus may be on other Edittexts if there is multiple edittexts

Answer (score 0):

I have also found another solution for moving up layout components when Soft keyboard appers.

It can be achieved using **`adjustResize`** attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Main purpose of `adjustResize` attribute is the activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

To show Keyboard and moved up `EditText` at start of `Activity` you need to use like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will works for you:
Add this statement in manifest file to your Activity:
**android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"**

```
  <activity
        android:name="ConversationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_conversations"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```