# EditText appearing from the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to create something like in Youtube app's comments section - when you click a reply button, an `EditText` pops from the bottom of the screen along with keyboard

[image]

Does anybody know how making a view like that is possible? Is it a snackbar/bottom sheet?

Comment: [Have you gone through this question. It may help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536827/how-to-have-an-edittext-stuck-to-the-soft-keyboard-on-android)

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, but I think it's a little different concept. I'd want to have the `EditText` "floating" above the screen, instead of shifting everything up; I'd also like to make the background grey out, like in the attached screenshot.